# How to add grid-lines when using geom tile in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to recreate a plot from the `corrplot` package but in `ggplot` in R. The first code block below shows the plot that I am trying to recreate.

```
#create data
set.seed(100)
m <- matrix(runif(25, -1, 1), ncol = 5)
rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <- LETTERS[1:5]
m[lower.tri(m)] = t(m)[lower.tri(m)]
diag(m) <- 0

col1 <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(10,"BrBG"))

corrplot::corrplot(m, 
                   method = "square", 
                   col = col1(100))
```

The above code creates this plot:

[image: heatmap]

my attempt at recreating it using ggplot:

```
# Convert the correlation matrix to a data frame
df <- reshape2::melt(m)
df$abs <- abs(df$value)
df$Var1 <- factor(df$Var1, levels = colnames(m))

# Create a custom tile size function
tile_size <- function(x) {
  min_size <- 0.5
  max_size <- 1
  return((x - min(df$abs)) / (max(df$abs) - min(df$abs)) * (max_size - min_size) + min_size)
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(aes(width = tile_size(abs), height = tile_size(abs))) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df$Var1))) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colors = col1(100),
    limits = c(-1,1)) +
theme_bw() +
theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

My code makes this plot:

[image: heatmap2]

The main aspect that I'm trying to recreate are the gridlines surrounding each tile seen in the first figure. Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to add the boxes around each tile via a second `geom_tile`. Additionally I removed the default expansion of the axes and the grid lines and added an alternative approach to your `tile_size` function using `scales::rescale`, which also takes account of the range of the (abolute value) of a correlation which is `c(0, 1)`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# Create a custom tile size function
tile_size <- function(x, min_size = 0.5,  max_size = 1) {
  scales::rescale(x, from = c(0, 1), to = c(min_size, max_size))
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(aes(width = 1, height = 1), fill = NA, color = "grey50") +
  geom_tile(aes(width = tile_size(abs), height = tile_size(abs))) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df$Var1)), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colors = col1(100),
    limits = c(-1, 1)
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 1,
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]